# Passing arguments between scripts?

Tags: javascript, npm

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "run-something",
    ....
```

I call my script via:

```
npm run dev
```

This is shorthand and just runs the regular command `npm-run-development`.

How can I pass arguments from the shorthand command to the regular command? For example how can the test argument be passed from `npm run dev`, to `npm run development`?

```
npm run dev -- --test=abc
```

Comment: Try adding `--` at the end of `npm run development` like so: `npm run development --`. Does that work?

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `--` to the end of your shorthand commands should work:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "npm run development --",
   "development": "run-something",
```